# Get context in Image onload function

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have an array of Image objects like

```
var array = [];

...

array[i].onload = function () {
    ...
}
```

In the onload function I want to know which Image object is this function binded to. Is there a way to know that?

Comment: Use `this` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arbitrary parameters to onLoad. Check the example below.

https://gist.github.com/prabindh/8177375